# How can I perform this cumulative sum in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate a cumulative sum of the values in column 2 of `dat.txt` below for each string of ones in column 1. The desired output is shown as `dat2.txt`:

```
dat.txt  dat2.txt
1 20     1 20  20   % 20 + 0
1 22     1 22  42   % 20 + 22
1 20     1 20  62   % 42 + 20
0 11     0 11  11
0 12     0 12  12
1 99     1 99  99   % 99 + 0   
1 20     1 20  119  % 20 + 99
1 50     1 50  169  % 50 + 119
```

Here's my initial attempt:

```
fid=fopen('dat.txt');
A  =textscan(fid,'%f%f');
in =cell2mat(A); 
fclose(fid);

i = find(in(2:end,1) == 1 & in(1:end-1,1)==1)+1;
out = in;
cumulative =in;
cumulative(i,2)=cumulative (i-1,2)+ cumulative(i,2);

fid = fopen('dat2.txt','wt');
format short g;
fprintf(fid,'%g\t%g\t%g\n',[out cumulative(:)]');
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a completely vectorized (albeit somewhat confusing-looking) solution that uses the functions [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html) and [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) along with [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) to produce the results you want:

```
>> data = [1 20;...  %# Initial data
           1 22;...
           1 20;...
           0 11;...
           0 12;...
           1 99;...
           1 20;...
           1 50];
>> data(:,3) = cumsum(data(:,2));       %# Add a third column containing the
                                        %#   cumulative sum of column 2
>> index = (diff([0; data(:,1)]) > 0);  %# Find a logical index showing where
                                        %#   continuous groups of ones start
>> offset = cumsum(index.*(data(:,3)-data(:,2)));  %# An adjustment required to
                                                   %#   zero the cumulative sum
                                                   %#   at the start of a group
                                                   %#   of ones
>> data(:,3) = data(:,3)-offset;        %# Apply the offset adjustment
>> index = (data(:,1) == 0);            %# Find a logical index showing where
                                        %#   the first column is zero
>> data(index,3) = data(index,2)        %# For each zero in column 1 set the
                                        %#   value in column 3 to be equal to
data =                                  %#   the value in column 2

     1    20    20
     1    22    42
     1    20    62
     0    11    11
     0    12    12
     1    99    99
     1    20   119
     1    50   169
```

Comment: I wonder if the function DIFF only applicable to test one condition? If I want to find cumulative sum which fullfill two conditions, how to do that without using the function FIND?

Answer (score 3):

Not completely vectorized solution (it loops through the segments of sequential 1s), but should be faster. It's doing only 2 loops for your data. Uses MATLAB's [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html) function.

```
istart = find(diff([0; d(:,1)])==1); %# start indices of sequential 1s
iend = find(diff([d(:,1); 0])==-1); %# end indices of sequential 1s

dcum = d(:,2);
for ind = 1:numel(istart)
    dcum(istart(ind):iend(ind)) = cumsum(dcum(istart(ind):iend(ind)));
end

dlmwrite('dat2.txt',[d dcum],'\t') %# write the tab-delimited file
```

Comment: With the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use `bwlabel` to find the connected groups of 1's

Comment: @Jonas: I remember this from your answer to another question. Don't have IPT here to test. Anyway, my code is pretty simple. The challenge is how to do cumsum for all groups without for-loop. If we'd have the complete groups in a cell array, we could use CELLFUN. I will be happy to see an example using bwlabel, since I face with similar problem all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    d=[
1 20     
1 22     
1 20     
0 11     
0 12     
1 99     
1 20     
1 50
];
disp(d)

out=d;
%add a column
out(:,3)=0;

csum=0;
for(ind=1:length(d(:,2)))
    if(d(ind,1)==0)
        csum=0;           
        out(ind,3)=d(ind,2);    
    else
        csum=csum+d(ind,2);
        out(ind,3)=csum;    
    end

end

disp(out)
```

Comment: hash blue@ is it possible to just use FIND function and not use LOOP?