# MATLAB how to perform cumsum which fulfill two conditions?

Tags: matlab, cumulative-sum

This question is related to [How can I perform this cumulative sum in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101893/how-can-i-perform-this-cumulative-sum-in-matlab).

Is it possible to use TWO conditions to perform cumsum? or just one condition?

EDITED:

```
data = [1 22 20;...  %# Initial data
        1 22 22;...
        1 22 20;...
        1 44 11;...
        0 44 12;...
        1 33 99;...
        1 33 20;...
        1 33 50];
```

I want to find cumulative sum which fulfilled 2 conditions:

```
% 1) current row in column 1 = 1 && previous row in column 1==1;
% 2) current row in column 2 = previous row in column 2

data(:,4) = cumsum(data(:,3)); % Add a 4th column containing 
                               % the cumulative sum of column 3
index  = diff([0;data(:,1)])> 0 && diff([0;data(:,2); 0])~= 0; 
offset = cumsum(index.*(data(:,4)-data(:,3)));  
data(:,4) = data(:,4)-offset;        
index = (data(:,1) == 0); 
data(index,4) = data(index,3)
```

Intended output:

```
data = [1 22 20 20   >> 20 + 0
        1 22 20 40   >> 20 + 20
        1 44 11 84   >> 11 + 40
        0 44 12 12   >> 12 + 0
        1 33 99 99   >> 99 + 0
        1 33 20 119  >> 20 + 99
        0 33 50 50   >> 50 + 0
```

EDITED:
With the code below, I got the wrong output.

```
index = diff([0;data(:,1)])> 0 & diff([0;data(:,2)])~=0

 1    22    20    20
 1    22    22    42
 1    22    20    62
 1    44    11    73 %this supposed to be 11 not 73 ..
 0    44    12    12
 1    33    99    99
 1    33    20   119
 1    33    50   169
```

Comment: What errors does your code produce ?  If you don't tell us we'll find it (more) difficult to diagnose your problem.  And a sample of your data would help too.

Comment: ??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical
scalar values.

Comment: it seems really that you want a sort of piece-wise cumulative sum, that is, one where the cumulative sums starts over each time column 2 changes -- is this correct?

Comment: also, why is `data(3,4) = 84` in your example? shouldn't it be `11` with `data(4,4) = 11` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm slow and don't yet really understand what you are trying to do.  Could you describe it in words ?  When you do, separate the specification of which elements of your array data you want to operate on, and the specification of the cumulative sum  The Matlab function `cumsum` does not take any conditions, you have to write Matlab statements to select the data you want to sum first.

Your second condition `data(1:end-1)==data(2:end)` looks suspicious to me since they use linear indexing which is probably not what you want.  If you don't understand the term *linear indexing* try experimenting with a few references such as data(4) and data(24), ie one-dimensional indices into a two-dimensional array.

So the statement

```
index = diff([0;data(:,1)])> 0 && diff([0;data(:,2); 0])~= 0;
```

raises errors.  What you have to do here is use Matlab interactively to build up the statement you want to execute piece-bypiece.  So, does

```
[0;data(:,1)]
```

produce the result you expect ?  Do you understand what it produces ?  Next, ask the same questions of

```
diff([0;data(:,1)])
```

and then of

```
diff([0;data(:,1)])> 0
```

and keep going.  At some point you will discover that Matlab does not do what you expect -- and this is because your expectation is wrong.

Finally, one thing that is definitely wrong is that the sub-expressions `diff([0;data(:,1)])> 0` and `diff([0;data(:,2); 0])~= 0` produce vectors with different lengths.

**EDIT:**  The operator `&` may be what you want since it will operate element-by-element on your two arrays.

**EDIT 2**: I'm afraid I have no more time to help you on this one, so I suggest you rewrite your program to explicitly loop over the data array building the cumulative sum as it goes.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I want to find a cumulative sum which row in column 1 = 1 and current row in column2 = previous row in column 2

Comment: @Jessy: I don't understand your comment.  Which columns do you want to sum, and which columns do you want to match ?  All of them ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have changed the output. column that I want to sum is the 3rd column, and I want to match column 1 and column 2. current row in column 1=current row in column 1, and current row in column 2 == previous row on column 2.

Answer (score 0):

Following your question as written (just satisfying the two conditions you have) you need an expression for index like this:

```
index = data(:,1) & ([0;diff(data(:,2))] == 0);
```

Note this *only* applies the cumulative sum where both of your conditions (restated below) are satisfied:

1. rows where column 1 is 1
2. rows where column 2 matches the previous row or is the first row

For me, this produces an output of

```
data(index,4) = cumsum(data(index,3))
data =

     1    22    20    20
     1    22    22    42
     1    22    20    62
     1    44    11     0
     0    44    12     0
     1    33    99     0
     1    33    20    82
     1    33    50   132
```

That said, this won't produce your desired output, so either your conditions or the desired output are wrong.